# Best practices for extending Custom User Model in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have a Custom User model in my app

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    uuid = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, unique=True)
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), db_index=True, unique=True)
```

and this `AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.User'` in my settings file.

Now I want to create a model on the top of this custom user model(User), lets call it Agent, this model will have three columns:

```
user_uuid #Foreign Key Refernce(OnetoOne) to the Custom User Model
uuid # unique identifier for Agent model
scope # CharField specific to Agent model
```

What is the best way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

While there is no best practice, it all depends on what you are doing, the most likely to work method is a `type` field specifying `Agent` and a [one-to-one table (docs)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/examples/one_to_one/) for extra fields.

It'll be up to you to create the records as-needed.  There isn't anything special about what you are doing just because it is a user.

```
class AgentDetails(Model):
    user = OneToOneField(User, primary_key=True, on_delete=CASCADE)
    ...
```

A more complete user model would look something like this:

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    EMAIL_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ["name"]

    email = EmailField(unique=True, db_index=True)
    name = CharField(max_length=100)
    type = ChoiceField(choices=[('user','User'),('agent','Agent')])
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False, help_text='If the user can log into this admin site.')
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True, help_text='If the user is active, instead of deleting')
    created_at = models.DateTimeField('Date Joined', default=timezone.now)

    objects = MyUserManager() #
```

In addition, you are probably going to need to add:

1. Custom admin page
2. Custom UserManager

You *can* derive one table from an abstract base, but this will generate 1 table for each user type which will not work with the standard authentication.  For info, see [Django's Model Inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/models/#model-inheritance).

```
class User(Model):
    email = EmailField()

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class Agent(User): # generates table 1
    extra_field = CharField()

class Standard(User): # generates table 2
    extra_field = CharField()
```

If the user model you have given is complete, then I don't think it will work with the default django infrastructure.   From your question its not clear if you need help on that.

Comment: Apologies for the confusion, I have a complete User model in my application but there is a new requirement wherein I need to support a different set of users through by system and hence the table Agent for them. I am writing a custom authentication to support the APIs from these users.